# How to loop SQL statement multiple times

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I try to loop one sql statement multiple times to retrieve the weekly revenue of on particular store. Here is my best guess which does not work.

```
SELECT * 
    DECLARE @i int = 0
    WHILE @i < 52 BEGIN
        SET @i = @i + 1
        FROM dbo.revenue
        WHERE DATEPART(WW, date) = @i
        AND storenumber = '005'
    END
```

Comment: This won't work, what is your actual problem? Looks like http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: Don't use loops but set based approaches http://sqlperformance.com/2013/01/t-sql-queries/generate-a-set-1

Comment: Can't you just group by DATEPART(WW, date), sum and ask for the relevant store

Comment: @HoneyBadger this is not on purpose, just not knowing how to think set-based

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You actually never want to write loops in SQL.

```
SELECT
  SUM(earnings) weekly_earnings
FROM
  dbo.revenue
WHERE
  storenumber = '005'
  AND date >= '2015-01-01'
  AND date < '2016-01-01'
GROUP BY
  DATEPART(WW, date)
```

Left join that against a helper table that contains 52 rows (1 through 52) representing the weeks to fill in the blanks (weeks with no revenue).

Note that the `date >= '2015-01-01' AND date < '2016-01-01'` exists because:

- you must limit the query to one year, or the week number becomes ambiguous
- it is superior to `DATEPART(YY, date) = 2015` because, being a calculation, that expression would not be able to use an index on the `date` column, whereas `>=` and `<` can use an index

---

EDIT: Instead of a temporary table you can use a [recursive CTE](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186243(v=sql.105).aspx) on SQL Server:

```
WITH WeekNumbers (WkNum) AS (
  SELECT 1 AS WkNum
  UNION ALL
  SELECT w.WkNum + 1 FROM WeekNumbers w WHERE w.WkNum <= 52
)
SELECT
  w.WkNum,
  SUM(r.earnings) weekly_earnings
FROM
  WeekNumbers w
  LEFT JOIN dbo.revenue r ON w.WkNum = DATEPART(WW, r.date) 
WHERE
  r.storenumber = '005'
  AND r.date >= '2015-01-01'
  AND r.date < '2016-01-01'
GROUP BY
  w.WkNum
```

Comment: The calendar table is an excellent point to cater for weeks with no revenue.

Comment: Thank you. I'm not used to think like this.

Comment: @greg121 Yes, the set-based approach takes some getting used to, but learning it is absolutely inevitable.

Comment: @Tomalak also great you added the recursive CTE version. But when looking at it, I see a CTE with 52 entries which is joined on the actual table. where is the recursion?

Comment: The recursion is happening in the CTE, it's self-referential. That's how it generates the 52 rows.

Answer (score 2):

You could just group your data and use some aggregation?

```
Select Sum(Revenue) AS [TotalRevenuePerWeek],
       DatePart(ww, RevenueDate) as [WeekNumber]

From dbo.Revenue
Where StoreNumber = '005'
And DatePart(year, RevenueDate) = 2015
Group By DatePart(ww, RevenueDate)
```